# Fluent Design card lift effect

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, fluent-design, fluent-kit

I want to add the card lift effect to my [bootstrap cards with fluent design styles](https://nespero.com/fluent/jquery/docs/content/card/) on hover. You can see what I mean on [microsoft design website](https://www.microsoft.com/design/).

Here's what I tried, but there is something missing and I cannot quite grab it.

I tried:

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: -3px 6px 5px 0px rgba(176,164,176,1);
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: -3px 18px 20px 0px rgba(99,89,99,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="width:19.5rem">
  <div class="card-body">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit ameta, card content
  </div>
</div>
```

Kindly thanks for your help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What makes the effect to looks like it is lifting is the `transform: translate3d`, [see translate3d w3cschools docs](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_3dtransforms.asp).

When the `box-shadow` changes on `:hover` the element itself moves in a different position, delivering the effect.

So by giving `transform: translate3d(0px, -1px, 0px);` ( translate3d(x,y,z) ), the element moves `1px` **up** and shadow casts **down**.

```css
.card {
  padding: 15px; /* JUST TO LOOK COOL */
  border: 1px solid #eee;  /* JUST TO LOOK COOL */
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0px 2px 4px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) 0px 19px 43px;
  transform: translate3d(0px, -1px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="width:19.5rem">
  <div class="card-body">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit ameta, card content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one. Do you think I should add it to my [Fluent Kit](https://nespero.com/fluent/jquery/) library? Also, is that not a little overkill to use `translate3d` just to lift it up by `1px`? Can you think of any better solution?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the actual movement upward. Many ways to achieve this, for example:

```
.card:hover {
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

from the top of my head.

Comment: That's what the other guy said, but he used `translate3d` instead. Which one do you think is better for that particular effect? Any pros/cons for one over another? If it is identified with Fluent Design System I think I might add it to the library mentioned, what do you think?

Comment: you would have to run performance tests to figure this out.. i just use 'margin' because it seems simpler.. would like to see how you go with this though.

Comment: OK, thanks for your insights, it makes sense with using the margin as you point out - simplicity. I will definitely let you know what I decided on in the next few days, cheers.

Comment: `margin-top: -1px` can be used indeed, but in this case it will move the whole content below it 1px up as well... `transform:` will only change it visually, nowhere else will be affected.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this effect, microsoft uses multiple box-shadows like so:

```
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0px 2px 4px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 0.5px 1px;
```

on hover:

```
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) 0px 19px 43px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18) 0px 4px 11px;
```

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0px 2px 4px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 0.5px 1px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) 0px 19px 43px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18) 0px 4px 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" style="width:19.5rem">
  <div class="card-body">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit ameta, card content
  </div>
</div>
```